# Unsigned version of lldiv in C?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc

I have a function which needs the quotient and remainder for an unsigned 64-bit division.  It looks like lldiv and lldiv_t, while `long long int`s rather than `int`s, are signed.  Is there an unsigned version?  If not, what's the best way to handle this?

Speed is important (as usual, billions or trillions of operations), but the compiler *might* be smart enough to handle this properly -- I'm using gcc 4.3.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the division and remainder operators. Any sane compiler will do a much better job optimizing them than a call to `div`, `ldiv`, or `lldiv`.

Comment: +1. FYI, GCC usually converts division on long long/unsigned long long to calls into libgcc anyway, which is typically targeted to your system (or architecture). / and % are the way to go, along with -O[123] (and makes your code neater as well).

Comment: @Matthew: On that note, you can actually greatly improve performance by defining your own version of the functions from libgcc written in asm. For example, gcc's `__udivdi3` makes absolutely no use of the fact that 64/32->32 division where the high word of the numerator is less than the denominator is a single `div` instruction. Just noting this lets you replace most real-world calls to `__udivdi3` with a single predictable branch followed by `div`. Of course gcc should be making this optimization *before* calling `__udivdi3` when it can, but we all know gcc....